# Socket.io client doesn't connect to server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have developed a simple chat using socket.io on a vagrant environment and it works correctly.

When I try to run the chat on the production environment, the nodejs/socket.io server runs but the client doesn't even fire the connect event.
The only thing I've modified is, in the client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
```

to:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://ip_address:3000');
```

This is the server code:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server is running');
});
function handler(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('');
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('subscribe', function() {
        console.log('subscribe request has arrived');
        console.log(socket.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it worked locally and stopped working after deployment, it's probably a network issue - firewall, blocked port, linux enforcing or something of that sort.

To find the source, go to the host server and try connecting the port

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 3000
```

Did you get 'Connection refused' error? if so which server is running the code? make sure firewall service is either off or with exceptions for port 3000. on linux check [enforcing](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/Permissive_versus_enforcing) .

If the connection succeed, test the connection from your local pc

```
 telnet ip_address 3000
```

If it fails than test access to external service (for example [portquiz.net](http://portquiz.net:3000/)) This way you will know if the issue is with your local pc or network, or the remove server.

Comment: The 3000 port was blocked by the firewall. Now it works perfectly..Thank you very much!

Comment: On my case I specified the listen address which restricted who could connect. Changing it to ''. Solved the connection refused issue.

eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', int(server_port))), app)